# image tag not being rendered in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I am trying to use a slide to switch images and am transposing code from a working web page to work under rails but it seems the image tag isn't being rendered.
Rails 4.2.0

rendered page shows

`<li class="show"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>`

original page 

`<li class="show"><% image_tag("test.png", size:"950x350") %></li>
        <li><% image_tag("test1.png", size:"950x350") %></li>
        <li><% image_tag("test2.png", size:"950x350") %></li>
        <li><% image_tag("test3.png", size:"950x350") %></li>`

I am not seeing any errors in the logs.

I suspect this is some thing simple I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put equal symbol

```
<%= image_tag("test1.png", size:"950x350") %>
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was somthing simple

Comment: lol. I remember making this mistake every time and then being stuck for n-number of minutes contemplating my actions and stupidity! (no offense, this is the silliest mistake I think quite a lot of beginners make) :D

Comment: Initially i use to do this mistake for form tag ...:P